# Loading Dygraph input inside a node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, routes, dygraphs

I'm very new to node and am struggling to load the data for Dygraphs on a static page.  I believe that my issue is to do with routing.  My js for Dygraphs is:

```
g2 = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
  "../newDataFile.csv",
  etc....
```

I can see in the browser that newDataFile.csv is not being loaded, despite the file being in the root directory.

My routing code looks like this:

```
router.get('/Dygraphpage', function(req, res) {
  res.render('Dygraphpage');
});
```

I guess that I need to pass the csv file into this routing code, but I don't know how to.  Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I am using ExpressJS and the solution was to put the newDataFile.csv inside the Public folder.  It then existed at /newDataFile.csv.